# Changing the visibility of a div according to body class with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, visibility

How to JS this?

If *body* has **class "classA"**
Then *display:block* **class "visibleclass"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($('body.classA').length > 0)
    $('.visibleclass').css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (/\bclassA\b/.test(document.body.className)) {
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName('visibleclass'),
        len = els.length, i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        els[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

But why?

Comment: Why? I have a div that I want to hide except in one page. I'm building on wordpress so that div is in a template that's used by all the other pages. By the way I couldn't get this work. I've jquery installed as well.

Comment: I understand the problem quite well. My question was rather why you would use JavaScript to solve it instead of 2 lines of CSS.